# ruby on rails: how to change the routing address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, custom-routes

I am new to rails and I would like to know that if there is a way to change the name of the routes. I will explain the sentence in a minute. I have a **controller** named **users_controller** and below is the code that I have in my controller:

```
def create
  if @user.save
  redirect_to @user
end
```

And my **routes.rb** file is as below:

```
resources :users

get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

Now suppose I have a form and I fill it correctly then I will be redirected to `localhost:3000/users/id(id = some value)` which I do. Now I want this URL to be like `localhost:3000/registered` . That is when i click the submit button and if everything is correct I wanted to see the URL as `localhost:3000/registered` which takes me to my **show action** or which works just like `localhost:3000/users/id(id = some value)`. I don't want the ID to be visible.

For this I tried `get 'registered', to: 'users#show'` but still I see the same URL as `localhost:3000/users/id(id = some value)`. Please tell me how to do this.

And here is my **show action**

```
def show

@user = User.find(params[:id])

end
```

I tried another way by making another action into the same controller. I made **index action** in my **users_controller** and executed then I got a **No method Error**

Comment: The [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is excellent.

Comment: I referred that. and from there I got this idea get 'registered', to: 'users#show'

Comment: shoud I change my controller to something else rather using @user

Comment: something like redirect_to registered_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, from the discussions I had it has been cleared that there is no way to hide your ID, but we can change the way they appear on the browser. One and suggested way is to create a **hash** for the **ID** and use it to display the item in **show action** or the other way is to redirect your action to some **static page**.

Answer (score 5):

Just use your routing as:

```
match "/registered", :to => "users#show", :as => :user_registered, via: :get
```

to use this path you will use

```
redirect_to user_registered_path(id: user_id)
```

in your method.

Comment: but how will it know that its a GET or POST

Comment: sorry my bad!add this in the end:
via: method
method being get or post

Comment: let me check fot this way. :)

Comment: could not find a user without ID it says :(

Comment: are you we can change the route for a "show" action, because it was suggested to me that we cannot

Comment: `localhost:3000/registered` is the one showing this error

Comment: redirect_to user_registered_path(user.id)

Comment: sorry don't know where my mind is... you need to pass the user.id as a param

Comment: still not able to get it... :(

Comment: now it comes like "registered.ID". But I dont want this ID to be seen

Comment: but its finding the user correctly now? if yes then lets work on the .id problem now

Comment: Well the id is required in the url and can not be done without, however there are ways to use other identifiers such as unique username, otherwise it will be best to create a landing method that doesn't require an id.

Comment: how to do the second option

Comment: i mean landing method that doesnot require an id

Comment: well create an action with generic info, and show the user that page after they register

Comment: you mean a static page

Comment: because we require something from database to find so that we can show the users their name or other info

Comment: do you use any gem for user management? devise being first choice usual

Comment: how about adding constraints?

Comment: if your username is unique you can use that to show in the url

Comment: or store the id in session to retrieve the info.

Comment: Actually i was thinking of either using the constraints on ID or as you said storing it in a seesion

Comment: but when i do this `match 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', :constraints => {:id => /[A-Z]+/}, via: :get` it does not work

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by constraints on ID, so I think session is the way to go, and use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user management. It will make these things really easy.

Comment: I didn't know how constraints work, so thanks for the share I'll read about them, and what error are you getting?

Comment: What I understand from url constraints is that it forces the id to be of certain type, I do not know how you are going to use it to hide your id in the request?

Comment: atleast i can change it to something else

Comment: I don't think it works like that, let me do a little search :)

Comment: but nothing happened. it again shows me the same users/:id url

Comment: well constraint is just a check for sql injection and type checking of the parameter received...

Comment: what other thing I unique to the user except for his id?

Comment: I have thier email Id

Comment: Lol... it will still be open to attacks of people shuffling through emails of friends or foes, go with the session, that will be the best approach.

Comment: i guess that will be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `redirect_to` in your user controller's `create` and `update` actions.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
     # get user from params
    if @user.save
      redirect_to registered_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
     # get user from params
    if @user.save
      redirect_to registered_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: As we discussed in the comments, you don't want to use `"users#show"`, since the registered page will look the same for every user. You can make your own registered controller to do this.

```
rails g controller registered index
```

Comment: Then it gives me an error that the page you are looking doesnot exists while running it on heroku

Comment: It says could not find an User without an ID

Comment: I think it has something to do with my Show action

Comment: I see the issue. The problem is that you're mapping `registered` to `"user#show"`, which expects an id for the user. Do you want to make a boiler plate registered page for all users, or are you looking to make a registered page that's unique for each user?

Comment: I want all users to see the same show page just with their names in it when they log in. You can suppose it as a Thank you page for some site.

Comment: If user#show expects an ID then should I try changing the the name of action from sho to something different?

Comment: Yes. Just make your own action. `rails g controller registered index` should get everything you need to get started on your registered/thank you page.

Comment: i tried creating a new action called index in my users_controller and then i made a call and I got No method error. Ihave updated my question. please have a look at it

Comment: You need to make the `index` action in the **RegisteredController**, not the UsersController. Or, you need to `get "registered", to "users#index"`.

Comment: I did both. lets try it step by step. I HAVE MADE INDEX IN REGISTERED_CONTROLLER

Comment: I get an error saying Undefined local variable register_path in UsersController

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51642/discussion-between-jken13579-and-ror)